# ¿Cómo recibir parámetros de distintos métodos en uno solo método?

Tags: java

Tengo 5 métodos de la siguiente forma:

```
  public void CalcularCandidato5 (String d1, String d2, String d3, String d4, String d5, int TVC5)
{
    int D1, D2, D3, D4, D5;

    D1 = Integer.parseInt(d1);
    D2 = Integer.parseInt(d2);
    D3 = Integer.parseInt(d3);
    D4 = Integer.parseInt(d4);
    D5 = Integer.parseInt(d5);

    TVC5 = (D1 + D2 + D3 + D4 + D5);  
}
```

Todos poseen la estructura anterior, la única diferencia en cada uno es que en el último parámetro del encabezado, cada uno posee uno distinto, o sea: TVC1, TVC2, TVC3, TVC4 y TVC5.
**¿Qué estructura debe poseer el método que va a recibir a estos cinco parámetros y cómo los envío al mismo?**

Comment: Hola amigo, no entiendo tu pregunta. si te refieres a como recibir diferente información del mismo tipo en un método, pues esa es la forma correcta es mas no necesitas crear otros 4 metodos mas. La idea de crear un metodo es evitar las tareas repetitivas. si esto no esponde la pregunta. prodrías explicar mejor lo que necesitas?

Comment: Así como hay CalcularCandidato5 hay CalcularCandidato1, 2, 3 y 4. Cada uno de estos métodos emite un parámetro llamada TVC 1, 2, 3, 4 Y 5 de forma correspondiente. Yo necesito saber, como enviar cada uno de estos 5 parámetros de 5 diferentes métodos, a un solo método que se llamará CalculaVotos. O sea, la pregunta sería: *¿Cómo pasar parámetros de diferentes métodos a otro método?* Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: cuál es el problema? por qué haces 5 métodos distintos?  con uno basta y listo. es decir por que no en vez de poner calcularCandidatos# pones un método que sea calcularCandidatos y los argumentos los pones genericos, total supongo que todas tus otras funciones hacen lo mismo

Answer (score 1):

Ok, acabo de contestar tu pregunta anterior en la cual das menos informacion, ahora que leo esto, comienzo a entender...

Tienes dos opciones:

1.- Cambiar el tipo de dato de tus metodos para que regresen el dato que quieres y despues hacer lo que te respondi en la otra pregunta.

```
//Cambia el tipo de dato de void a int
public int CalcularCandidato5(...){
    /*Aqui lo demas*/
    //Agrega una ultima linea que regrese el dato
    TVC5 = (D1 + D2 + D3 + D4 + D5);
    return TVC5;
}
//Cuando quieras invocar dentro del codigo que corre, hazlo asi:
/*
    metodoD( CalcularCandidato1(...),
             CalcularCandidato2(...),
             CalcularCandidato3(...),
             CalcularCandidato4(...),
             CalcularCandidato5(...) );
*/
```

2.- Veo que no declaras TVC5, si esto es porque ya tienes una referencia a este de manera global, entonces solo correlo todo y manda tus parametros normalmente...

```
public class claseX{
    int TVC1;
    int TVC2;
    int TVC3;
    int TVC4;
    int TVC5;
/*
    AQUI IMAGINA QUE ESTAN LOS METODOS DE LOS QUE HABLAS, "CalcularCandidatoN".
*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalcularCandidato1("1","2","4","8","16");
        //CUANDO LA EJECUCION LLEGUE A ESTA LINEA, YA HAY INFORMACION EN TVC1
        CalcularCandidato2("32","64","128","256","512");
        CalcularCandidato3("32","64","128","256","512");
        CalcularCandidato4("32","64","128","256","512");
        CalcularCandidato5("32","64","128","256","512");
        //CUANDO LA EJECUCION LLEGUE A ESTA LINEA, YA HAY INFORMACION EN TVC2, TVC3, TVC4 y TVC5 tambien
        metodoD(TVC1,TVC2,TVC3,TVC4,TVC5);
    }

    //Asumiendo que tienes ya un metodoD parecido a este:
    public static void metodoD(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e){
        /* Y aqui hacer lo que necesites */
    }

}
```

Para esta segunda opcion, considera que hice el metodoD estatico para que pudiera invocarse del main... si lo tienes dentro de una clase, no necesita ser estatico, basta con invocarlo del objeto que hayas creado (objeto.metodoD(...))